# Escaping XML at PHP 5

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, escaping

I am using an external script for my site and i found out that it seems there's a syntax problem when it tries to generate the XML code.

There are no quotes for the 2nd line and it makes the page crashing. How could i solve it? Why did it work for other people? Is it about the PHP version?

```
$h->xmlrequest = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; 
$h->xmlrequest .= <<<END 
<a:searchrequest xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/security/"> 
  <a:sql> 
     SELECT "DAV:displayname" 
     ,"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" 
     FROM "$exchange_server/Exchange/aaaaa/inbox" 
  </a:sql> 
</a:searchrequest> 
END;
```

The problem makes the PHP file not ableto be executed and therefore not showing any external output. 
Even just trying this makes it crash:

```
$h->xmlrequest = '<'.'?xml version="1.0"?'.'>'; 
$h->xmlrequest .= <<<END 
END;
```

Displaying errors this is the error i get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fromMail\index2.php on line 23
```

Line 23 is the one of <<< END

Comment: is `$exchange_server` a PHP variable that you want to output into the string?

Comment: it would help if you could be more specific in telling us what the error is that your getting rather than just saying "a syntax problem".

Comment: you're not showing any code indentation in the question. Just to be sure, you know that the `END` marker has to be completely un-indented, right? (it looks right here, but just checking)

Comment: With syntax problem i mean the PHP file can not even be executed. So when i try to load the page, it just doesn't show anything (not even in the source code). If i delete the XML conflictive lines, then it works and it shows some stuff.

Comment: Yeah, @SDC, it is completely left-aligned.

Comment: you say it crashes, but **what is the error message???**

Comment: @Steve Please add the `display_errors = 1`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the displaying error.

Comment: Ok, now i have solved it. It seems it was because after the first <<<END there was a white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this one is really tricky to spot: You've got spare whitespace at the end of the `<<<END` line:

```
$h->xmlrequest .= <<<END 
//----------------------^
```

Therefore the ending

```
END;
```

doesn't match anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$h->xmlrequest = '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
```

To:

```
$h->xmlrequest = '<'.'?xml version="1.0"?'.'>';
```

Comment: no -- if it's in a string (which it is), then it won't be parsed as a PHP `?>` closing tag.

Comment: @SDC I too had issues this way. Made the above fix so that it got fixed.

Comment: I have updated the question with more info. Take a look at the very simple XML code that makes it crash.

Comment: Why do you need the `HEREDOC` extra syntax there?

Answer (score 1):

There was a white space after the first  <<< END

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change the line

```
$h->xmlrequest = '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
```

to

```
$h->xmlrequest = '<' . '?xml version="1.0"?' . '>';
```

would do the trick as the parser thinks the `?>` means the end of the PHP script.

Comment: no -- if it's in a string (which it is), then it won't be parsed as a PHP `?>` closing tag.

Comment: @SDC - I will double check - but I have experienced a similar problem even if it is in a string (if you old memory serves me correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the `$exchange_server` variable name in braces, otherwise although PHP will try to parse it, it can be affected by the code around it.

ie in your case, the slash character after $exchange_server may be confusing the PHP parser.

so...

```
$h->xmlrequest .= <<<END 
<a:searchrequest xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/security/"> 
  <a:sql> 
     SELECT "DAV:displayname" 
     ,"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" 
     FROM "{$exchange_server}/Exchange/aaaaa/inbox" 
  </a:sql> 
</a:searchrequest> 
END;
```

The braces will ensure that the variable is parsed correctly, no matter what is around it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried it now. It still doesn't print anything. It might be a syntax problem for sure... (and it's on this lines)